# i am trying to with with tkinter in colab and problem is like basic marksheet generation i am getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

i am getting this error TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
should i include matplotlib or something else and i am working on colab.

```
# Import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter as tk 
  
# creating a new tkinter window 
master = tk.Tk()  
  
# assigning a title 
master.title("MARKSHEET") 
  
# specifying geomtery for window size  
master.geometry("700x250")  
  
and the rest of the code  
     
master.mainloop()
```

why this error and what can be done??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't elaborate your question enough. It would be nice if you share the complete traceback, what OS you use, what python version you use, what modules you use etc... But without any info several reasons are possible.

If you use `matplotlib` module. `matplotlib` chooses `Xwindows backend` by default. You need to set `matplotlib` to NOT use the `Xwindows backend`.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

If you run your code via `SSH`. You should set the `-X` parameter.

```
ssh -X user@hostname
```

You should try to export the `DISPLAY` environment variable:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Comment: OP already stated that he is using `Google Colab`.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. In that case probably this is the answer for the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168385/11502612

Comment: thanks for the answers i got to know that colab doesn't support gui windows

Comment: But why this answer is accepted as it is actually not the answer to the question?