# Google Colab hang with tkinter ( python module )

Tags: python, tkinter, google-colaboratory

i have tried to test [Deaf Communicator GitHub project](https://github.com/shubham-thakare/deaf-communicator)  via google colab notebook as you can see here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LdZEEuwKkIHfydVI3lhMfk1QjWbHDUb7?usp=sharing

[image]

this GitHub project needs tkinter python muddle and based of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168210/is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory) i tried to use below codes to fix  colab problem with tkinter module, but the problem is that it hang on running these commands:

```
!apt-get install -y xvfb # Install X Virtual Frame Buffer
import os
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    # create virtual display with size 1600x1200 and 16 bit color. Color can be changed to 24 or 8
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0'    # tell X clients to use our virtual DISPLAY :1.0
%cd /content/deaf-communicator
!python -m DEAF.py
```

with this result :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  xvfb
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 783 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,266 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 xvfb amd64 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.7 [783 kB]
Fetched 783 kB in 1s (1,117 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package xvfb.
(Reading database ... 144655 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../xvfb_2%3a1.19.6-1ubuntu4.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking xvfb (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.7) ...
Setting up xvfb (2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
/content/deaf-communicator
```

[image]

so if possible take a look on it to fix that bugs.
Also asked here:
https://github.com/shubham-thakare/deaf-communicator/issues/1

thanks.

Comment: How were you expecting this to work, actually?  Colab code is running on a remote server, all you've done here is tricked your GUI into producing output on a virtual display *that you have no way of viewing*.

Comment: So can i run it via [Colab VPS like this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1x0b1GE7vsQiT1tP_Y9Hl_yBhYdrKIEqL#scrollTo=qYE7WQzCQNnd)?