# Python TclError w/Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, google-colaboratory

Coding in Python using Google Colab and getting this error when running the following code:-

```py
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import smtplib

# Initialize Tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
```

ERROR:-

```sh
TclError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-01f10ba55e31> in <module>()
      8 
      9 # Initialize Tkinter
---> 10 root = tkinter.Tk()
     11 root.withdraw()
     12
```

What can I change to fix it?

Comment: Does "[is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168210/is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory)" help?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes! Thank you