# Error in GoogleColab (Python)- TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, tkinter, google-colaboratory

Does anybody know how to fix the below error in Python in GoogleColab Notebook? I am running the below code:-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

import numpy
import keras 
from keras.models import load_model

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

model = load_model('training_model.h5')

classes = { 1: 'Speed Limit 20 km/h',
            2: 'Speed Limit 30 km/h',
            3: 'Speed Limit 50 km/h' }

#initialize GUI

top = tk.Tk()
top.geometry('800x600')
top.title('Traffic Sign Recognition Project Report')
top.configure(background='#EEE')

label=Label(top,background='#CDCDCD', font=('arial',15,'bold'))

sign_image = Label(top)
```

I get the error on the line `-> top = tk.Tk()`

Comment: There are alot of same questions here, have you checked it?

Comment: Yup, but no one worked for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not possible to use `tkinter` on `Google Colaboratory` for alot of reasons. Firstly, even though if you manage to get it working by following [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168385/13382000), as it mentions:

> However, if you want to interact with the GUI, that's going to be hard, 'cuz Colab doesn't support interactive screens out of the box.

also from other answers there:

> Servers generally don't even have a display. And even if they had, you wouldn't see it. You will have to run Python on your desktop or laptop to use tkinter.

I cannot close this question as a duplicate because the other question does not have a correct answer chosen.

Comment: Updates: I managed to use the thinker library by running locally the project through the Anaconda -> Jupyter Notebook.