# Trying to use gui on Colab

Tags: user-interface, google-colaboratory

I am trying to build a gui on Colab, via Tkinter.
The original project is here:
https://github.com/julrog/nn_vis
I already know that the problem is due to code being executed on Google cloud server, the problem is how can I build a gui, or more precisely can I ever link it to my local laptop to be visualized, use XMing, or something like this? (my OS is Windows

Answer (score 1):

[As ivan_pozdeev says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168385/17733080), you need to run a framebuffer server (that will emulate a graphical screen) and create a DISPLAY envvar pointing to it.

```
!apt-get install -y xvfb # Install X Virtual Frame Buffer
import os
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    # create virtual display with size 1600x1200 and 16 bit color. Color can be changed to 24 or 8
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0'    # tell X clients to use our virtual DISPLAY :1.0
```

However, if you want to interact with the GUI, that's going to be hard, 'cuz Colab doesn't support interactive screens out of the box.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: did not work for me. i got an errror "maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" when i call  env.play()