# How to use GUI in Google Colab?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, google-colaboratory

How can i use tkiner on google colab? I am facing the following error while running it.

[image: Screenshot of the error]

If it is not possible then how can i transfer a trained model from google colab to local environment in python IDLE

Comment: You can't. It works through browser only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to use Tkinter with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168210/is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory)

Answer (score 2):

**No, you can not.**

The notebooks execute code on Google's cloud servers and you would not be able to see a display.

You could try to run a framebuffer server and a `DISPLAY` pointing to it to emulate a graphical screen as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796670/run-gym-gazebo-on-google-colaboratory), but it could become a challenge for itself since Colab doesn't natively support interactive screens.