# I got this error on Google Colab: couldn't connect to display ":1.0"

Tags: python, tkinter, google-colaboratory

I tried to use tkinter on Google Colab. And I got the error:

```
TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

And I tried this method in this answer: [Is there any way to use Tkinter with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168210/is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory)

But still I got an error:

```
TclError: couldn't connect to display ":1.0"
```

Here is my code:

```
import random
import os
from tkinter import *

import numpy as np

!apt-get install -y xvfb # Install X Virtual Frame Buffer
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0'
```

You guys didn't understand what is going on here...
I read the answers from [How to use GUI in Google Colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62806893/how-to-use-gui-in-google-colab) and [Is there any way to use Tkinter with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168210/is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory) and I think they are not answering my question.

Somebody asked if it is possible to use Tkinter in Google Colab in this question: [Is there any way to use Tkinter with Google Colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61168210/is-there-any-way-to-use-tkinter-with-google-colaboratory), and the first answer asserted that adding these lines of code into the very beginning would be helpful.

```
!apt-get install -y xvfb 
os.system('Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16  &')    
os.environ['DISPLAY']=':1.0'
```

It says this will create a virtual display so that we can use Tkinter in Google Colab. I tried this and it failed. So now I am asking why it failed.

I know some answers stated that you cannot use a GUI on Google Colab. BUT there are answers saying that it is possible to create a virtual display. However after doing what they said, I still got the error I posted. So I am wondering is it really impossible to use tkinter in Colab or it is that whatever code from other answers that I used has something wrong with them and that can be fixed.

Please consider reopening this question as I think this is not a duplicated question.